# Videoplayer issue in android

Tags: android

Hello
In my android application i am playing live rtsp links.
The issue is at times if the player gets struck somewhere then the videoplayer doesnot exit even if we press back.
The only option will be to close the program from task manager.

Is there any way that i can make it better?

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is your code getting stuck, be sure that you are not doing anything (especially network operations) that can block or take more than a few milliseconds in the UI thread - you need to be doing that in loopers or services.

If it's the underlying android video player engine that is hanging, sorry, no idea.